# The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string without connection string

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am creating a simple console application using the code first approach its my first application in code first.I created two model classes named Student and Standard and one context class,but when i tried to add the object in the context it gives me the error
The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
In this approach i am not using any connection string, I am using Vs2010,Sql server2008r2 and entity framework version 6.0

Comment: Do you have any database installed? Is it accessible? You could read the connection string using `ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` and use it to see if you can access the database.